# desktop run time parameters in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I need to take pass input parameters to a console application and retrieve the output parameters using a batch file.

The steps are:

1. Run the console app with input parameters. (This is how the program currently runs.)
2. I would then like to wait for a response from the console app before proceeding to the next step.  The program needs to wait because it is calling a web service.  I need to make certain the response code call to the web service = 0.
3. Next step depends on the response from the web service.

   a. If the response from the web service = 0, then the console app is called again with parameters to close out the customer account on the web service.

   Also under this step, the results for the second call to the console app should be displayed in a message the user can see.

   b. If the response from the web service not = 0, then a message should be displayed to the user stating what the problem is. No further call is made.

Thus can you show me code and/or point me to a reference on how to accomplish this goal?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Having read through this a couple times, I think you might want to investigate powershell.  It's much better at handling a LOT of common scripting things you might want to do.

Comment: Too many details left unclear. What does input parameters mean - do you mean command line args or read from stdin? how does the console app return the response - is it returning it as a return value to the shell? What the are parameters to close out the customer account on the web service? How does the batch file get the results of the 2nd call to the webservice?

Comment: At least you could specificate the programming language of your console app.

Comment: Elektro Hacker:  The language the console app was written in doesn't matter.  He is trying to use a batch file to start it and get a response back.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this again.
Here is batch code that should do what I *think* you want.

```
@echo off
call myApp.exe %*
set result=%errorlevel%
echo result = %result%

if %result%==0 call myApp.exe close (or whatever the paramaters are)
if %result%==1 echo "Message explaining what error code 1 means"
if %result%==2 echo "Message explaining what error code 2 means"
...
```

This will call myApp.exe with whatever paramaters you pass into the batch file. You can replace the `%*` with hard coded input if you need.  This then prints the exit code of the application and can eather call it again to close or print a message explaining the error code.

---

Modified from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "externalExecutable.exe";
p.Arguments = "-arg1 -arg2";
p.Start();
// Wait for the child process to exit before
// reading to the end of its redirected stream.
p.WaitForExit();
// Read the output stream
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
// Parse the output to see what you should do
// Or just use the exit code from the proccess
if (output.Equals("0") || p.ExitCode == 0) {
   // Do what you need to in this case
} else {
   // Do something else here
}
```

Comment: This is c# code.  The OP is actually looking for how to make a batch file.

Comment: @Chris: lol, oops. I thought I had the C# filter on when I was looking at questions.

Comment: I guess I did (just looked back at your edit), I just had the C# frame of mind when answering.

Comment: The original question was a bit confusing.  It took me a few times of reading before I figured out that he wanted to kick off the console app with a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this generic function in vbnet, really don't know if this gonna help you 'cause we don't know which language are you talking about.

Whit this func you can wait and read process output (process CMD for example):

```
#Region " Run Process Function "

    ' [ Run Process Function ]
    '
    ' // By Elektro H@cker
    '
    ' Examples :
    '
    ' MsgBox(Run_Process("Process.exe")) 
    ' MsgBox(Run_Process("Process.exe", "Arguments"))
    ' MsgBox(Run_Process("CMD.exe", "/C Dir /B", True))
    ' MsgBox(Run_Process("CMD.exe", "/C @Echo OFF & For /L %X in (0,1,50000) Do (Echo %X)", False, False))
    ' MsgBox(Run_Process("CMD.exe", "/C Dir /B /S %SYSTEMDRIVE%\*", , False, 500))
    '  If Run_Process("CMD.exe", "/C Dir /B", True).Contains("File.txt") Then MsgBox("File found")

    Private Function Run_Process(ByVal Process_Name As String, Optional Process_Arguments As String = Nothing, Optional Read_Output As Boolean = False, Optional Process_Hide As Boolean = False, Optional Process_TimeOut As Integer = 999999999)

        ' Returns True if "Read_Output" argument is False and Process was finished OK
        ' Returns False if ExitCode is not "0"
        ' Returns Nothing if process can't be found or can't be started
        ' Returns "ErrorOutput" or "StandardOutput" (In that priority) if Read_Output argument is set to True.

        Try

            Dim My_Process As New Process()
            Dim My_Process_Info As New ProcessStartInfo()

            My_Process_Info.FileName = Process_Name ' Process filename
            My_Process_Info.Arguments = Process_Arguments ' Process arguments
            My_Process_Info.CreateNoWindow = Process_Hide ' Show or hide the process Window
            My_Process_Info.UseShellExecute = False ' Don't use system shell to execute the process
            My_Process_Info.RedirectStandardOutput = Read_Output '  Redirect (1) Output
            My_Process_Info.RedirectStandardError = Read_Output ' Redirect non (1) Output
            My_Process.EnableRaisingEvents = True ' Raise events
            My_Process.StartInfo = My_Process_Info
            My_Process.Start() ' Run the process NOW

            My_Process.WaitForExit(Process_TimeOut) ' Wait X ms to kill the process (Default value is 999999999 ms which is 277 Hours)

            Dim ERRORLEVEL = My_Process.ExitCode ' Stores the ExitCode of the process
            If Not ERRORLEVEL = 0 Then Return False ' Returns the Exitcode if is not 0

            If Read_Output = True Then
                Dim Process_ErrorOutput As String = My_Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() ' Stores the Error Output (If any)
                Dim Process_StandardOutput As String = My_Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() ' Stores the Standard Output (If any)
                ' Return output by priority
                If Process_ErrorOutput IsNot Nothing Then Return Process_ErrorOutput ' Returns the ErrorOutput (if any)
                If Process_StandardOutput IsNot Nothing Then Return Process_StandardOutput ' Returns the StandardOutput (if any)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return Nothing ' Returns nothing if the process can't be found or started.
        End Try

        Return True ' Returns True if Read_Output argument is set to False and the process finished without errors.

    End Function

#End Region
```

Comment: The current application that is being accessed is C# 2008 desktop application. Would this change your answer?

Comment: @user1816979 No because I don't use C# but you can easy translate the snippet with an online or offline .NET code converter. Also you have the Cemafor answer wich you can combine with my snippet.

Comment: The "language" he was talking about is a regular windows batch file.